# Looking for really trippy animated movie

Tags: story-identification, animation

A few years back, I saw this clip on Youtube. It was animated with a seemingly very incoherent story. It could potentially be about a hero going on a mission to defeat an evil being or something. The main character is a rather buff guy and the animation style is similar to He-Man. I think the clip was between 30 to 45 minutes long.

I was hypnotized for like 10 minutes by it because I couldn't figure out what was wrong. But then it dawned on me. The faces, the backgrounds, the colors, and essentially every small detail was changing ever so slightly every 5-10 seconds. It's subtle enough that you don't consciously notice it at first but you definitely notice something weird going on and it completely screws with your head.

I can't for the life of me remember what the name was. I've tried searching for it for hours without success.

Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: If you were logged in to YouTube you could look through your history.

Comment: Thanks @amflare. I added in a few more details.

Comment: Are you sure, like really sure, you weren't just seriously high when you watched it?

Comment: @wikis Sadly, I wasn't logged in to my Youtube account. Good tip though.

Comment: @Binary, well I didn't want to include it in the question but yes I was. That's why it screwed with my head so much and why it took me such a long time to figure out what the hell was going in. But I am definitely sure that all the details were changing, I studied it intensely for like 30 minutes.

Comment: Hmm... was it sort of a sketchy style of animation, or did it look more realistic? If the former, I wonder if this was one of the MTV Liquid Television sketches. Many of them were done in a way that looked like the frames were being redrawn from scratch each time, created a very distinct wavery outline setup and it would make sense that background details would change too.

Comment: And Liquid Television was indeed generally trippy. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKc2_QIO0Yo

Comment: Fire and Ice directed by Ralph Bakshi https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_and_Ice_(1983_film) ... It has a he-man like protagonist on a quest, somewhat incoherent storytelling, and an animation style based on rotoscoping that could be interpreted as giving an uncomfortable feeling of shifting details

Comment: Not confident enough to add an answer, but my mind immediately lept to The Treasure Planet (NOT the Disney one) whenever I read this question. Look familiar? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnXqQs29FgI

Comment: Something by Chad VanGaalen, maybe?

Comment: Could it have been a section from the Heavy Metal Movie? https://youtu.be/s7e3T0qxKqw

Comment: Maybe it could be Bobobo (add more Bo's if neccessary). The most acid try to manga and anime I know...

Answer (score 4):

This sort of sounds like the "Den" segment in the Heavy Metal movie. If you saw it on Youtube, it may have been just that segment.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niC6Jq6aI2o